# Responding to clicking a specific column of a Vaadin table row

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am new to Vaadin.
I have three different views.
View1 has a table with column1,column2. For a particular table row,when i click on column1,i want to navigate to view2 and when i click on column2 i want to be able to navigate to view3. I can respond to the row click as a whole using the ValueChanged event.But how do i handle click on the specific column of the row?
The way i am handling the row-click is as follows

```
summaryTable.addValueChangeListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChange(Property.ValueChangeEvent event) {
        String provider = summaryTable.getContainerProperty(summaryTable.getValue(), "provider").toString();
        UI.getCurrent().getNavigator().navigateTo(ViewsEnum.PROVIDERS.viewName()+"/"+provider);
    }
});
```

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic in the below code gave me the column i clicked on. I am using the value of selectedColumn in valueChange() to determine which View i want to navigate to.

```
summaryTable.addItemClickListener(new ItemClickEvent.ItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        selectedColumn = (String)event.getPropertyId();
    }
});
```

Not sure if that's the right way to do it or is just a hack.
I am sure there is a better way around.Please sugggest!

Comment: ItemClickListener is the way to go.

Comment: I am doubtful about this approach considering we can't guarantee the order in which itemclickevent and valuechangeevent are triggered

Comment: That's true. Do you really want that the table is also selectable?

Comment: If i dont have the table as selectable, how else am i supposed to trigger the events?

Comment: You can move logic from valueChange to itemClick.

Comment: i tried doing that.it fails to get the right row that is clicked..When i do   String provider = summaryTable.getContainerProperty(summaryTable.getValue(), "provider").toString();,it gets me the provider value for the first row. The reason could be because i am setting summaryTable.setValue(((Integer)summaryTable.firstItemId()));..If i remove this,it doesnt work.So i doubt if itemclick doesnt help in my case.